# Xcode 10 visual recognition problem with swift 4.2

Tags: carthage, xcode10, swift4.2

After Xcode upgrade to 10, my app is not working anymore and I get this error:

> Module compiled with Swift 4.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.

If I update Carthage I pass the build but my app crashes with this error:

> Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 4.1.2
>   (swiftlang-902.0.54 clang-902.0.39.2) and the local version is 4.2
>   (swiftlang-1000.11.37.1 clang-1000.11.45.1).

When it finishes I pass the build but the app crashes with this error:

> dyld`__abort_with_payload: dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/RestKit.framework/RestKit   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AA66442D-02F3-4728-9489-F5B903B1252B/what.app/Frameworks/VisualRecognitionV3.framework/VisualRecognitionV3
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Did you rebuild the packages with carthage's `update` command?

Comment: how do I do that ? I run Carthage update --platform ios when did the update

Comment: Then you should be fine unless you have two versions of Xcode (9 and 10) and Carthage is using earlier one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the RestKit framework binary. I was focused on the visual recognition framework but the error was indicating the missing RestKit framework. What is curious is that it did work without it with Xcode 9.